# Triangle of numbers maximum path - Greedy algorithm Python

Tags: python, performance

A triangle of numbers path maximized using a greedy algorithm. It's not the most efficient way since I'm a beginner this is the best I could do.
I need your feedback on how to make it better in terms of maximizing the total. It works in a way that it chooses the highest value of the adjacent numbers in the next row. No brute forcing(might take forever with big numbers). I also included a lot of functions that do different things(check the docstrings) including making triangle of size n, reading a triangle from a file ... I want your feedback on how to make things better in terms of optimization/style...

```
from time import time
import random


def make_row(n, not_str=False):
    """Makes a row of size n; not_str = True to return integers.
    Returns a list containing row, if not_str = True, a list of strings(numbers) is returned."""
    temp = []
    for i in range(n):
        if not_str:
            temp.append((random.randint(10, 99)))
        else:
            temp.append(str(random.randint(10, 99)))
    return temp


def make_triangle(n, not_str=False):
    """Makes a triangle of numbers of size n.
    Returns triangle, a list of lists(rows); if not_str = True, a list of strings is returned else: integers."""
    triangle = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if not_str:
            temp = make_row(i, not_str)
            triangle.append(temp)
        else:
            temp = make_row(i)
            triangle.append(temp)
    return triangle


def save_triangle(n, filename):
    """Assumes filename a string(name of the file) and n size of the triangle to make.
    Writes triangle to 'filename'."""
    triangle = make_triangle(n)
    triangle_file = open(filename, 'a+')
    for row in triangle:
        row = ' '. join(row)
        triangle_file.writelines(row + '\n')
    triangle_file.close()


def triangle_to_list(triangle, p=False):
    """Assumes triangle a list or a string and p = True to print triangle.
    Returns a list of lists(rows) containing integers."""
    # If triangle is not a list(ex: a .txt file or a string, clean from new lines and spaces.
    if not isinstance(triangle, list):
        rows = triangle.split('\n')
        # If p, print the triangle of numbers and the size.
        if p:
            print(f'Triangle of size {len(rows)}')
            print()
            for rw in rows:
                print(''.join(rw))
        # Clean from spaces
        while '' in rows:
            rows.remove('')
        row_nums = [x.split(' ') for x in rows]
        all_rows = []
        # Convert strings to integers.
        for row in row_nums:
            temp = []
            for num in row:
                temp.append(int(num))
            all_rows.append(temp)
        # Returns a list of integers.
        return all_rows
    # If triangle is produced using make_triangle, it's a list.
    if isinstance(triangle, list):
        rows = triangle
        # If p, print the triangle of numbers and the size.
        if p:
            print(f'Triangle of size {len(rows)}')
            print()
            # Convert from integers to strings to print using .join().
            list_of_strings_to_print = []
            for row in rows:
                temp = []
                for number in row:
                    temp.append(str(number))
                list_of_strings_to_print.append(temp)
            for row in list_of_strings_to_print:
                print(' '.join(row))
            print()
        # Returns a list of integers.
        return rows


def triangle_file_list(filename, p=False):
    """Assumes 'filename' contains a triangle of numbers(strings), p = True to print. Returns a list of lists(rows) containing integers."""
    with open(filename, 'r') as tri:
        triangle_file = tri.read()
        #
        if p:
            print(triangle_file)
        raw_triangle = ''.join(triangle_file)
        return triangle_to_list(raw_triangle)


def maximize_path(rows, p=False):
    """Assumes rows is a list of lists containing all rows and p = True to print path.
    Returns total of the maximum path.
    """
    start = 0
    total = 0
    # This list contains number, index in the row (to prevent miscalculations in case of row duplicates), next number).
    choice_combinations = []
    while start < len(rows) - 1:
        for index, number in enumerate(rows[start]):
            next_max = (max(rows[start + 1][index], rows[start + 1][index + 1]))
            if next_max == rows[start + 1][index]:
                choice_combinations.append((number, index, next_max))
            if next_max == rows[start + 1][index + 1]:
                choice_combinations.append((number, index + 1, next_max))
        start += 1
    final_choices = [choice_combinations[0]]
    for number, index, next_number in choice_combinations[1:]:
        # Performing 2 checks: check by number and check by index.
        if number == final_choices[-1][-1] and any((index == final_choices[-1][1], final_choices[-1][1] == index - 1)):
            final_choices.append((number, index, next_number))
    for item in final_choices:
        total += item[0]
    total += final_choices[-1][-1]
    # If p, print the maximum path, sum.
    if p:
        print('Maximum path:')
        for item in final_choices:
            print(f'{item[0]} --> ', end='')
        print(final_choices[-1][-1])
        print()
        print(f'Maximum sum: {total}')
    return total


def test_triangles(n, one=False):
    """Assumes n is the maximum size of the triangles to print, prints n triangles, n paths, n sums, n times.
    If one = True, prints only one triangle of size n."""
    time_all = time()
    if one:
        time1 = time()
        tr = make_triangle(n, True)
        rws = triangle_to_list(tr, True)
        maximize_path(rws, True)
        print()
        print(f'Total time: {time() - time_all} seconds.')
    else:
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            time1 = time()
            tr = make_triangle(i, True)
            rws = triangle_to_list(tr, True)
            maximize_path(rws, True)
            print()
            print(f'Time taken: {time() - time1} seconds.')
            print()
        print(f'Total time: {time() - time_all} seconds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_triangles(20, True)
```

Comment: A greedy algorithm will not always give you the maximum, as it can be “baited” to follow a path which will avoid larger numbers later on.  An exhaustive search is \$O(2^N)\$, so will not work for larger triangles. The “clever” approach is only \$O(N^2)\$.  Since this is Project Euler #18 or #67 (from your deleted question), I’ll leave the discovery of the clever algorithm to you.  But as a hint, you only need to look at pairs of rows.  Top down 1&2, then 2&3, then 3&4, etc.; or bottom up. Another hint: Space requirement is \$O(N)\$ if you do not modify the input data.

Answer (score 1):

General suggestions:

1. [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) can automatically format your code to be more idiomatic.
2. [`isort`](https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort) can group and sort your imports automatically.
3. [`flake8`](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8) with a strict complexity limit will give you more hints to write idiomatic Python:

   ```
   [flake8]
   max-complexity = 4
   ignore = W503,E203
   ```

   That limit is not absolute by any means, but it's worth thinking hard whether you can keep it low whenever validation fails. For example, I'm working with a team on an application since a year now, and our complexity limit is up to 7 in only one place.
4. I would then recommend adding [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) everywhere (I'm not sure whether they work with Python 2 though) and validating them using a strict [`mypy`](https://github.com/python/mypy) configuration:

   ```
   [mypy]
   check_untyped_defs = true
   disallow_untyped_defs = true
   ignore_missing_imports = true
   no_implicit_optional = true
   warn_redundant_casts = true
   warn_return_any = true
   warn_unused_ignores = true
   ```

Specific suggestions:

1. Double negatives are really hard to follow. `not_str=False` is one such instance.
2. Boolean parameters are a code smell. Better to make two methods, optionally calling a third containing the common logic.
3. Naming is really important for maintainability - the only difference between names and comments is that names are actual code, and can trivially be refactored by tools. Names like `temp`, `i`, `n`, `one` and `rws` make the code unnecessarily hard to follow.

Comment: Type hints don't work in Python 2, but since the OP uses f-strings in his code, this should not be a concern.